# Encode array to uint8 and then back

Tags: python

I have an array which has intensity values from -3000 to 1000,I have thresholded all values which are less then -100 to -100 and all values greater than 400 to 400,After which i convert it to datatype np.uint8,Which makes all the values in the array to have intensity values from 0 to 255,

What i am confused about is,is there an operation i can run which will give the array from 0-255 intensity range to the earlier one -100 to 400?

Any suggestions will be useful,Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "then back" ? 256 numbers can't represent faithfully 500 numbers.

Comment: by 'then back' i mean, if there is any operation i could do which would reverse the uint8 operation and give me the previous array with -100 to 400 value intensity,kindly let me know if i am not clear enough

Comment: Do you just want to *store* your data? Otherwise it's impossible. Imagine you have 0,1,...,499; then you map them to 0,1,...255. There *must* be some conflict which makes your original data unrecoverable.

Comment: your right,I want to store the data.in uint8 beacuse it saves space,but since it represents data from 0-255, i was wondering if there was another operation which gives me the previous array back.Is that possible?@liliscent

Comment: `savez_compressed()` might help.

Comment: @liliscent Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

To store the given range after (the rather crude) threshold of [-3000, 1000] to [-100, 400] as an uint8, you would first need to map those values to the [0, 255] range before storing them as uint8. I chose a linear mapping here:

```
import numpy as np

def calculate_sum_of_errors(array_size):
    # random intensity values ranging from -3000 to 1000
    intensity_values = np.random.randint(-3000, 1000, array_size)
    # threshold to range [-100, 400]
    thresholded_values = np.clip(intensity_values, -100, 400)
    # lineary map the range [-100, 400] to the range [0, 256] - we choose 256 here instead of
    # 255 because only the outer range of our input array will produce this value, where as
    # if we choose to use 255 we loose more precision because only the outer range (400) 
    # will map to 255, instead we need this to be the last 'set' of the range instead
    mapped_values_best = np.array([(v + 100) / 500 * 256 for v in thresholded_values])
    # after the mapping, threshold to the range [0, 255] and store as uint8
    mapped_values = np.clip(mapped_values_best, 0, 255).astype('uint8')
    # do the reverse mapping (first convert to float so we can hold the values)
    restored_values = np.array([(v / 255 * 500 - 100) for v in mapped_values], 'int16')
    return sum(abs(thresholded_values - restored_values))

# just to see the 'error' of our ways, print the sum of the errors divided by the array size
print([calculate_sum_of_errors(s) / s for s in np.linspace(1, 10000, 100, dtype='int')])
```

Answer (score -2):

Try `array_name.encode("uint8").decode("uint8")` if this worked, then you can use the `decode()` method

Comment: let me check this

Comment: `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'encode'`